# I am an expression of a deer mint - Clue One

Tags: riddle, story

You wake up one morning, and immediately look over at the letter on your bedside table. It reads:

> Dear *[redacted]*:
>   You have been chosen to assemble the most powerful thing in the world - the *[redacted]* serum. It is composed of *[redacted]* clues. Your task: Decode the clues, and then assemble them. Good luck!
>
> P.S. If you cop out, we'll know. And you'll regret it.
>
> **The Riddle:**
>
> I am the color of first.
>   I am always good – I'll never be a brat.
>   I am made by number 2.
>   I am an expression of a deer mint.
>   What am I?

---

<sub>[Next clue --->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37993/a-long-but-relatively-easy-cipher-clue-two)</sub>

Comment: 'A deer mint' sounds very like a mishearing of 'endearment'. So perhaps an expression of endearment (darling, sweetheart, etc)? No clue how it fits with the rest though.

Comment: Does the "made by #2" mean the "good, not brat" made it?

Comment: Ohk, so after countably infinite clicks on the series of '<---Previous clue', i am finally here. Please fetch me one glass of warm water...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is

> Honey

I am the color of first.

> The 'color of first' being gold (e.g. gold medal), which is the color of honey. (@Brent Hackers for this one)

I am always good – I'll never be a brat.

> <strike>Honey is sweet, and sweet could be considered synonymous with 'good' and antonymous with 'being a brat'.</strike>
>  Honey doesn't spoil or 'go bad', i.e. it's always good.

I am made by number 2.

> Honey is made by a bee; 'B' is the 2nd letter.

I am an expression of a deer mint.

> 'Honey' is a common term of endearment (assuming the 'a deer mint' = 'endearment' theory ala @seasnake).

Comment: Very good answer... might be correct...although i m not too convinced on the 2nd one...

Comment: Dang that was not at all how I interpreted "number 2."

Answer (score 6):

I am the color of first.

> First place - gold medal?

I am always good – I'll never be a brat.

> Idiom - 'As good as gold'?

I am made by number 2.

> Have a couple of ideas but most seem a bit of a stretch.  Maybe, number 2 = 2nd place = silver which is used in the production of gold coins?

I am an expression of a deer mint.

> Something to do with the minting process?  Making coins of high value (dear?), especially gold coins, is called 'Minting'

What am I?

> Gold?

Comment: You got the first clue right, but none of the others. And wrong answer. :/

Comment: Interesting.  Nice puzzle!

Comment: "I am made by number 2" might literally mean the word consist of "two" or maybe the number "2"

Comment: Clue 3 might be referencing something that Clue 2 makes

Answer (score 2):

I am the color of first.

> First place = gold. Color spectrum of Helium = yellow

I am always good – I'll never be a brat.

> Noble gas = Does not react with other elements. Always stable.

I am made by number 2.

> Second element on the periodic table.

I am an expression of a deer mint.

> Mint is a deterrent for deer. Male "He" deer = Stag. Going stag (can't find date)? He does not bond with other elements.

What am I?

> Helium

Comment: Do you have an explanation for the 4th line, instead of 'hehe'?

Comment: Also, the correct answer has already been found, BTW.

Comment: Hehe, then I guess I won't likely find a connection for the 4th line. Almost matches though! Good puzzles. Thank you.

Comment: There, found a creative way to make it work.

Comment: That's disappointing. Why the DV? The answer may be incorrect (as a correct one was already discovered) but the responses all fit.

Comment: Probably because people here don't really like answers after the correct answer has been given. (wasn't me)

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Answer**

I am the color of first

> Gold (@BrentHackers)

I am always good - I'll never be a brat

> Angel

I am made by number 2

> Working on it

I am an expression of a deer mint

> Working on it

Comment: Nope for line 2.